# Setting two different roots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, root, sorcery

I am using the Sorcery gem for authentication - is there any way of setting two different roots? I want something like this in my routes.rb file.

```
if user = logged in
   root to: 'users#home'
else
   root to: 'users#landing'
end
```

From what I can tell, there only seems to be methods for doing this when using the Devise gem. Is there a way of using two different roots without using Devise?

Comment: Remember there's a *huge* difference between `=` and `==`.

Answer (score 4):

The router has no idea what `user` is, and nor should it. That's a controller concern. What you might do is have a single endpoint that behaves differently depending on your logged in status. Example:

```
def home
  if (logged_in?)
    render(action: 'landing')
  end
end
```

This will render `landing` if and only if you're logged in, otherwise `home`.